# Splitting Pandas column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to split a column into multiple columns? 
I have a columns in a dataframe where the contents are as follows:

```
a
[c,a]
b
```

I would like to split this into:

```
colA colB colC
a    nan  nan
a    nan   c
a     b   nan
```

Please note the order of variables in the 2nd row in the original column.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you have an `a` in the third row?

Comment: @DYZ, Thanks for pointing out the `a` in the third row. That is a mistake; it should not be present there.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(['a', ['c', 'a'], 'b'])

s

0         a
1    [c, a]
2         b
dtype: object
```

Use `pd.Series` and `'|'.join` to magically turn into concatenated pipe separated strings.  Use `str.get_dummies` to get array of zeros and ones.  Multiply that by the columns to replace ones with column values.  `where` masks the zeros and replaces with `np.NaN`.

```
d1 = s.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(pd.Series(x))).str.get_dummies()
d1.mul(d1.columns.values).where(d1.astype(bool))

     a    b    c
0    a  NaN  NaN
1    a  NaN    c
2  NaN    b  NaN
```

---

**PROJECT**/*`KILL`*

```
import itertools

n = len(s)
i = np.arange(n).repeat([len(x) if hasattr(x, '__len__') else 1 for x in s])
j, u = pd.factorize(list(itertools.chain(*s)))
m = u.size
b = np.bincount(i * m + j, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)
pd.DataFrame(np.where(b, u, np.NaN), columns=u)

     a    b    c
0    a  NaN  NaN
1    a  NaN    c
2  NaN    b  NaN
```

---

**Timing**

```
%%timeit
d1 = s.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(pd.Series(x))).str.get_dummies()
d1.mul(d1.columns.values).where(d1.astype(bool))

100 loops, best of 3: 2.58 ms per loop

%%timeit
n = len(s)
i = np.arange(n).repeat([len(x) if hasattr(x, '__len__') else 1 for x in s])
j, u = pd.factorize(list(itertools.chain(*s)))
m = u.size
b = np.bincount(i * m + j, minlength=n * m).reshape(n, m)
pd.DataFrame(np.where(b, u, np.NaN), columns=u)

1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop

%%timeit
s.apply(pd.Series)\
  .stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)\
  .pipe(lambda x: x.mul(x.columns.values))\
  .replace('',np.nan)\
  .add_prefix('col')

100 loops, best of 3: 4.24 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First stack the lists in the col column, get dummies for each element, and then transform them to a,b,c. Finally rename the columns.

```
df.col.apply(pd.Series)\
  .stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)\
  .pipe(lambda x: x.mul(x.columns.values))\
  .replace('',np.nan)\
  .add_prefix('col')
Out[204]: 
  cola colb colc
0    a  NaN  NaN
1    a  NaN    c
2  NaN    b  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get the column out as a series called s.

```
s = pd.Series(['a', ['c', 'a'], 'b'])
pd.DataFrame({"col" + x.upper(): s.apply(lambda n: x if x in n else np.NaN)
              for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```